# Duplicate Symbol XCode g++-4.2

Tags: c++, xcode, g++

OKay, so I'm trying to set some global variables that can be accessed by the rest of my program by including a header file. However, XCode is telling me that I have duplicate symbols. Can anyone help?

Error: Duplicate symbol _ArrowKey in /Path/to/MKDBControlInterface.o /Path/to/main.o

**main.h:** *// The global variables to be accessed...*

```
#ifndef _main_h
#define _main_h

#include <map>

std::map<int,bool> ArrowKey; 

#endif
```

**MKDBControlInterface.h:**

```
#ifndef _MKDBControlInterface_h
#define _MKDBControlInterface_h

#include <map>

#include <GLUT/glut.h>

#include "main.h"
#include "MKDBApplication.h"

class MKDBControlInterface {
public:
    MKDBControlInterface( MKDBApplication& App )
    : m_App( App )
    {
        glutSpecialFunc( SpecialListener ); 
        glutSpecialUpFunc( SpecialListenerX ); 

        ArrowKey[GLUT_KEY_LEFT] = false; 
        ArrowKey[GLUT_KEY_RIGHT] = false; 
        ArrowKey[GLUT_KEY_UP] = false; 
        ArrowKey[GLUT_KEY_DOWN] = false; 

    }

    ~MKDBControlInterface(){}

    void static SpecialListener( int key, int x, int y ){
        ArrowKey[key] = true; 
    }

    void static SpecialListenerX( int key, int x, int y ){
        ArrowKey[key] = false; 
    }
private:
    MKDBApplication& m_App; 

};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"

#include "MKDBApplication.h"
#include "MKDBControlInterface.h"
#include "MKDBRender.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    MKDBApplication App; 

    MKDBControlInterface Interface( App ); 
    MKDBRender Render( App ); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Is my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

In main.h you need to declare ArrowKey as

```
extern "C" std::map<int,bool> ArrowKey;
```

and in main.cpp after the includes you should define it:

```
std::map<int,bool> ArrowKey;
```

BTW, I would also replace `#ifndef/#define/#endif` with `#pragma once` in the headers.

Comment: Just extern...not extern "C" here--extern "C" is for functions.

Comment: The spec says 'extern string-literal declaration' without limiting declaration to a function :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! (without the "C" as mentioned above.  This happened to me after I changed the extention from m to mm to integrate an SDK for iOS.